# Is there a way to optimize my bigquery sql in order to run faster?

Tags: sql, optimization, google-bigquery

There are some columns that i want to fecth under the conditions.

**Columns are :**
point_id, weight(row currentness index 0 to 7, 0 is the most current row), localdate (YYYYmmdd), tmin(minimum temperature), tmax (maximum temperature) and precip_amount (precipitation amount mm).

**The conditions are :**
(localdate >= 20151201 AND localdate <= 20160104)  AND 
(tmin < 0 OR tmax < 0) AND precip_amount > 40

**My aim is to fetch the most current rows based on weight.**

I wrote a sql that works fine (2.7s elapsed, 64.4 MB processed).

But, is there a way to optimize my sql in order to run faster ?

**My sql :**

```
select a.point_id as point_id , a.weight as min_weight,a.localdate as local_date, a.tmin as temp_min, a.tmax as temp_max, a.precip_amount as precipitation
from table1 a
join (select point_id, min(weight) as min_weight
            from 
            (select point_id, localdate, tmin, tmax, precip_amount,weight
            from table1
            where (localdate >= 20151201 and localdate <= 20160104)  and (tmin < 0 or tmax < 0) and precip_amount > 40
            order by weight)
            group by point_id) b
on a.point_id = b.point_id and a.weight = b.min_weight
where (a.localdate >= 20151201 and a.localdate <= 20160104)  and (a.tmin < 0 OR a.tmax < 0) and a.precip_amount > 40
order by a.weight, a.localdate
```

Comment: Since BigQuery is a bigdata tool, you should not expect subsecond response time.

Comment: I just wonder why i shouldn't expect  subsecond response time. Thank you for your commend.

Comment: Any bigdata tool is setup to handle petabytes of data, and it's not optimized for small data sets, and you should not expect fast response time. The lowest I've seen are 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. I have moved calculation on minimum weight to subquery.

```
SELECT a.point_id as point_id, 
        (SELECT MIN(A2.weight) FROM Table A2
         WHERE A2.point_id = A.point_id
               AND A2.localdate >= 20151201 
               AND A2.localdate <= 20160104  
               AND (A2.tmin < 0 or A2.tmax < 0) 
               AND A2.precip_amount > 40) AS min_weight,
        A.localdate as local_date, 
        A.tmin as temp_min, 
        A.tmax as temp_max, 
        A.precip_amount as precipitation
FROM Table AS A
WHERE  A.localdate >= 20151201
       AND A.localdate <= 20160104 
       AND (A.tmin < 0 OR A.tmax < 0) 
       AND A.precip_amount > 40
ORDER BY A.weight, A.localdate
```

You can also try use windowed function. For example

```
SELECT T.* FROM
       (SELECT A.point_id,
               MIN(A.weight) OVER(PARTITION BY A.point_id) AS min_weight,
               A.localdate AS local_date,
               A.tmin AS temp_min,
               A.tmax AS temp_max,
               A.precip_amount as precipitation
        FROM Table A
        WHERE A.localdate >= 20151201
                   AND A.localdate <= 20160104 
                   AND (A.tmin < 0 OR A.tmax < 0) 
                   AND A.precip_amount > 40) AS T
    ORDER BY T.min_weight, 
             T.localdate
```

Comment: The first sql got error which is "Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause".The second sql works fine and it reduces execution time 2.7 seconds to 2.1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
( select a.point_id as point_id , a.weight as min_weight,a.localdate as local_date, a.tmin as temp_min, a.tmax as temp_max, a.precip_amount as precipitation  
       , row_number() over (partition by point_id order by weight asc) as rn
    from table1 a
   where (a.localdate >= 20151201 and a.localdate <= 20160104)   
     and (a.tmin < 0 OR a.tmax < 0) 
     and a.precip_amount > 40
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
order by tt.weight, tt.localdate
```

Comment: There is an improvement. My sql's execution time is  2.7 seconds. The sql in your answer's execution time is 2.5 seconds. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a window function:

```
select point_id, a.weight as min_weight, local_date, temp_min, temp_max,
       precip_amount
from (select a.point_id as point_id, a.weight,
             a.localdate as local_date, a.tmin as temp_min, a.tmax as temp_max,
             a.precip_amount as precipitation,
             min(weight) over (partition by point_id) as min_weight
     from table1 a
     where (a.localdate >= 20151201 and a.localdate <= 20160104) and
           (a.tmin < 0 OR a.tmax < 0) and a.precip_amount > 40
    ) a
where a.weight = w.min_weight
order by a.weight, a.localdate;
```

Comment: the sql got error which is  'Encountered " "ON" "on "" at line 8, column 6. Was expecting: ")" '